# How to change state when localStorage value changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How to change state when `localStorage` value changed. For example, I have a language switching button, like French and English, when I click English, it will be storing to `localStorage`, when I click English it will also.

When I click the French the whole project need to see in French, also when I click English, want to do like that, it  So how can I change state when I update `localStorage`?

```
<button onclick={()=>localStorage.setItem("language",'english')}>English</button>
<button onclick={()=>localStorage.setItem("language",'french')}>French</button>
```

```
let language;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  if (localStorage.getItem("language") === null) {
    language = "english";
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("language") !== null) {
    language = localStorage.getItem("language");
  }
}

const [langu, setLangua] = useState(language);

console.log(langu);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to achieve this that wouldn't change that much your current structure is first to change your buttons to this:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    localStorage.setItem("language", "english");
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
  }}
>
  English
</button>
<button
  onClick={() => {
    localStorage.setItem("language", "french");
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
  }}
>
  French
</button>
```

And then set up inside the component where you have `setLangua` and `langu` an `useEffect` that would listen to changes in the `localStorage` and update the state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const listenStorageChange = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("language") === null) {
      setLangua("english");
    } else {
      setLangua(localStorage.getItem("language"));
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("storage", listenStorageChange);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("storage", listenStorageChange);
}, []);
```

Comment: yeah , bro, it's working , i changed something. like ```if(typeOf(window !== undefined){}``` but it's working well now . thank you , thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

you need set it in `useEffect` hook, with empty dependences, it will run only when the component mount.

```
const [langu,setLangua] = useState(language)
useEffect(() => {
let language = ""
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if ( localStorage.getItem("language")  === null) {
        language = "english"
    }

    if ( localStorage.getItem("language")  !== null) {
        language = localStorage.getItem("language")
    }
}
setLanguage(language)
}, [])
```

Comment: // it will only need when the component mount , so, that's not my need , the user maybe frequently changes their language . so what can i do in that case ?

Comment: You can use a `Context` if you want to populate the state in all your components that listen to the language change, For more resources https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: It's better than listen to the storage event everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can setLangua at the same time as putting it in local storage. Or you can [subscribe to local storage changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) with the useEffect hook.

```
    import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

    const [userLang, setUserLang] = useState('english')

    const getLangFromLocalStorage = useCallback(() => {
        return localStorage.getItem('userLang');
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      function checkUserLang() {
        const value = getLangFromLocalStorage()
    
        // Do with value what you want
    
        if (value) {
          setUserLang(value)
        }
      }
    
      window.addEventListener('storage', checkUserLang)
    
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('storage', checkUserLang)
      }
    }, [])

    // Set userLang initially when component did mount

    useEffect(() => {
        const value = getLangFromLocalStorage();
        if (value) {
            setUserLang(value);
        }
    }, []);
```

`Note: This won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access the same storage objects.`

Comment: but it's not work for me , i added almost every where a log statement , but no one is printing when i change the language , it's only working when the component is mounting

Comment: @shamsudheen I'll check

Comment: @shamsudheen `Note: This won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access the same storage objects.`
So you can put that logic in the _app.js file and share state via React.context

Comment: I tried to put it into _app.js and it doesn't work. Because now that listener on each page. The listener and the buttons to set language to the local storage have to be on the different pages

Comment: I think @yousoumar gave you the right answer